# obtain owner name and group from stat function c++

Tags: c++, file, stat

Good day every one. I use function stat on windows to get information from file, but how i can get name from st_uid and st_gid (it's a short).

I use visual stydio 2015

Comment: Welcome! Please read before asking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you can't. `stat` is a POSIX function. The Windows function is actually called `_stat` to warn you it's not the same. And fundamentally, that's because the Windows user model differs *a lot* from the POSIX user model. Windows accounts and groups are not numbered, but use SID's. For instance, the SID of `Everyone` (group of all users) is `S-1-1-0`. Hence, the `st_uid` and `st_gid` fields returned by `_stat` are fairly meaningless.